# how to read content of pdf files and compare String with user input?

Tags: php, file, pdf

i have a PHP code that allow user select PDF files from specified destination. i need to allow the user to enter a string as user input  and make the system to read the content of all pdfs files and if the string exist in any PDF file display the file name.

until now i was able just to select PDF files.

## code:

```
<?php

    //path to directory
$directory = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/testwebsite\OSWebProject/";
$pdfs= glob($directory. "*.pdf") or DIE("Unable to open $directory");;

 if(isset($_POST["search"]))
{
     $NAME =$_POST['name'];
     echo $NAME ;

    foreach($pdfs as $pdfname ){
        echo $pdfname;

    }
} 
?>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
     <form action="test.php" method="post">
          <p>enter your string <input type ="text"  id = "idName"  name="name" /></p>
          <p><input type ="Submit" name ="search" value= "Search" /></p>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for `pdfgrep`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to convert all PDF files to text files with the `pdf-to-text` libary:

https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-text

Then store the text content in a database and make a search query.

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM pdf_files WHERE text_content LIKE :search");
$statement->execute(['search' => '%' . $search . '%']);

foreach ($statement as $row) {
    // do something with $row
}
```